# What is the relation between PATH_MAX and NAME_MAX, and how do I obtain?

Tags: python, c, posix, gnu, limits

In `limits.h`, and in various places in the POSIX manpages, there are references to `PATH_MAX` and `NAME_MAX`.
How do these relate to one another?
Where is the official documentation for them?
How can I obtain them at run time, and (where relevant) compile time for the C, Python, and GNU (shell) environments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PATH_MAX` is the maximum length of a filesystem path.  `NAME_MAX` is the maximum length of a filename (in a particular spot).  So, `/foo/bar` is restricted by `PATH_MAX`, and only the `bar` portion has its length limited by `NAME_MAX`.

You can get these at run time via `pathconf`, as `_PC_PATH_MAX` and `_PC_NAME_MAX`, although standard practice is generally just to use the static macros at compile time.  I suppose it would be better to use the run-time option because you could potentially support longer values that way, but I'm not sure what (if any) systems actually provide a return from `pathconf` which is greater than the value of the `POSIX_FOO_MAX` values.

Comment: Can you comment on whether or not they're available in Python, and where?

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Your question only really makes sense for C; there is no "compile time" for Python or shell scripting.  If you are using a scripting language, these variables are also unlikely to be useful to you - just use an indefinite-length string to manipulate your paths.  Also, these are system-specific variables, and a Python script should ideally be portable, so you may not want to make use of them and instead just check for "path too long" errors when creating/accessing a file.

Comment: I'm writing a filesystem in Python, so they are in fact of great interest. I'm calling `os.fpathconf` on my device file as a best guess for `PATH_MAX`, and `NAME_MAX` is a property of my implementation returned through `struct statvfs`. Despite missing the Python tips this is a good answer.

Comment: Most operating systems support execution of code compiled on an earlier version of the OS (or even on a different OS altogether). Should one of these values change during an OS update, calling `pathconf` in runtime gives you the correct (updated) value for the kernel/libc you're running on, vs. the incorrect (obsolete) value for the kernel/libc you compiled on.

Obviously it's superficially preferable to recompile for a new runtime, but that's not always possible or desirable in a specific instance.

Comment: Looks like POSIX actively forbids path components longer than `NAME_MAX`: pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/… : "If any pathname component is longer than {NAME_MAX}, the implementation shall consider this an error."