# What is the proper way to use inotify?

Tags: linux, inotify

I want to use the `inotify` mechanism on Linux. I want my application to know when a file `aaa` was changed. Can you please provide me with a sample how to do that?

Comment: Your trusted source of information should(and must) be the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). It contains a lucid example, all one could ever ask for! If you would like to have a full blown project reference, give [fluffy](https://github.com/six-k/fluffy/blob/master/libfluffy/fluffy.h) interface a look.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- Documentation ( from [Monitor file system activity with
  inotify](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-ubuntu-inotify/) )

**The `inotify` C API**

`inotify` provides three system calls to build file system monitors of all kinds:

- `inotify_init()` creates an instance of the `inotify` subsystem in the kernel and returns a file descriptor on success and `-1` on failure. Like other system calls, if `inotify_init()` fails, check `errno` for diagnostics.
- `inotify_add_watch()`, as its name implies, adds a **watch**. Each watch must provide a pathname and a list of pertinent events, where each event is specified by a constant, such as `IN_MODIFY`. To monitor more than one event, simply use the logical or — the pipe (|) operator in C—between each event. If `inotify_add_watch()` succeeds, the call returns a unique identifier for the registered watch; otherwise, it returns `-1`. Use the identifier to alter or remove the associated watch.
- `inotify_rm_watch()` removes a watch.

The `read()` and `close()` system calls are also needed. Given the descriptor yielded by `inotify_init()`, call `read()` to wait for alerts. Assuming a typical file descriptor, the application blocks pending the receipt of events, which are expressed as data in the stream. The common close() on the file descriptor yielded from `inotify_init()` deletes and frees all active watches as well as all memory associated with the inotify instance. (The typical reference count caveat applies here, too. All file descriptors associated with an instance must be closed before the memory consumed by the watches and by inotify is freed.)

- An example ( from [Kernel Korner - Intro to inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) )

> ```
> #include "inotify.h"  
> #include "inotify-syscalls.h"  
> int wd;   
> wd = inotify_add_watch (fd,   
>             "/home/rlove/Desktop", IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);
> if (wd < 0)
>       perror ("inotify_add_watch");
> ```

This example adds a watch on the directory /home/rlove/Desktop for any modifications, file creations or file deletions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why both you and Fabian chose not to give examples for shell scripting of inotify?

Comment: inotify itself is a Linux kernel API and not a user-space program you could use in a shell script. If you want to use the inotify API in your scripts, take a look at inotify-tools (https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).

Comment: I just use inotifywait/watch for my directories (via shell scripts). Is there something wrong with these two?

Comment: Please read my comment again. `inotifywait` is part of the mentioned inotify-tools. Additionally the original question was about a Qt application and not a shell script.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude here, but this answer does not satisfy the stackoverflow guidelines. This site is supposed to contain answers to questions. It is not LMGTFY. It is very common that I find answers on here that link to pages that no longer exist. What should be done in a stackoverflow answer is to put the relevant part of the linked page into the answer and CITE THE REFERENCE as to not plagiarize.

Comment: I concur with Richard - external links might become outdated one day, and this is essentially a way for google. But if we google, then we won't need stackoverflow.

Comment: As predicted, the IBM Developerwork links is now dead. IBM is kind of bad about this. I'll update the answer with a Wayback archive link from around the time when the question was originally asked.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides I updated the link with its new URL: https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-ubuntu-inotify

Answer (score 19):

Below is a snippet of how you can use inotify to watch "aaa". Note that I haven't tested this, I haven't even compiled it! You will need to add error checking to it.

Instead of using a blocking read you can also use poll/select on inotfd.

```
const char *filename = "aaa";
int inotfd = inotify_init();

int watch_desc = inotify_add_watch(inotfd, filename, IN_MODIFY);

size_t bufsiz = sizeof(struct inotify_event) + PATH_MAX + 1;
struct inotify_event* event = malloc(bufsiz);

/* wait for an event to occur */
read(inotfd, event, bufsiz);

/* process event struct here */
```

Comment: ⁺¹ for mention Qt, peoples who looks here from a search engine output could see, that the page have nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't contain `inotify_init()` in the example.  This one does.

Comment: what should be value of `PATH_MAX` ?

Comment: PATH_MAX is a constant https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325616/10183099

Answer (score 14):

If all you need is a commandline application, there is one called `inotifywait` that watches files using `inotify`

from terminal 1

```
# touch cheese
# while inotifywait -e modify cheese; do 
>   echo someone touched my cheese
> done
```

from terminal 2

```
echo lol >> cheese
```

here is what is seen on terminal 1

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
cheese MODIFY 
someone touched my cheese
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

**Update**: use with caution and see the comments.

Comment: Why use an erroneous and deprecated tool? If you had used it in production, you will feel my pain mate! Any way, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225008/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-files-within-folder-instead-of-folder/49349226#49349226) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673447/inotify-linux-watching-subdirectories/49345762#49345762) for a couple of reasons.

Comment: "It's a shame that inotifytools is hugely popular and unsuspecting users are unaware of its fallacies." XD nicely worded and cheers to you!

Answer (score 2):

Since the initial question seems to mention Qt as a tag as noted in several comments here, search engines may have lead you here.

If somebody want to know how to do it with Qt, see 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html for the Qt-version. On Linux it uses a subset of Inotify, if it is available, see explanation on the Qt page for details.

Basically the needed code looks like this:

in mainwindow.h add :

```
QFileSystemWatcher * watcher;
private slots:
    void directoryChanged(const QString & path);
    void fileChanged(const QString & path);
```

and for mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>

watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(fileChanged(const QString &)));
connect(watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(directoryChanged(const QString &)));
watcher->addPath("/tmp/"); // watch directory
watcher->addPath("/tmp/a.file");  // watch file
```

also add the slots in mainwindow.cpp which are called if a file/directory-change is noticed:

```
void MainWindow::directoryChanged(const QString & path) {
     qDebug() << path;
}
void MainWindow::fileChanged(const QString & path) {
     qDebug() << path;
}
```