# How to call a bash script automatically when directory contents chage

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

My goal is to run a bash script automatically whenever any new file is added to a particular directory or any subdirectory of that particular directory.

**Detail Scenario:**

I am creating an automated process for file submission from teachers to students and vice versa. Sender will upload file and it will be stored inside the **Uploads** directory in the LAMP server in the format, ex. "name_course-name_filename.pdf". I want some method so that when any file stored inside the Uploads folder, the same time a script will be called and send that file to the list of receives. 
From the database I can find the list of receiver for that particular course and student.

The only concern of mine is, how to call a script automatically and make it work on individual file whenever the content of the directory changes. Cron will do in intervals but not a real time work.

Comment: Have you seen [inotify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062806/inotify-how-to-use-it-linux)?

Comment: ya I have seen it, but, I have never used this and could not find any article describing properly the use of inotify to call abash script

Comment: You can use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for example.

Comment: "hek2mgl" has provided a solution for the same... let me check for it .

Comment: I got the solution working provided by "hek2mgl", but its not working inside the subdirectories, please suggest modification to the code provided by "hek2mgl" ... Thnks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run inotifywait continuously and run it as a cron or deamon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240994/how-to-run-inotifywait-continuously-and-run-it-as-a-cron-or-deamon)

Answer (score 4):

Linux provides a nice mechanism for that purpose which is called [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). `inotify` is mostly available as a C API. But there have been developed shell utilities as well. You should use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) from `inotifytools` (pkg name in debian) for this. Here comes a basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/tmp"   # or whatever you are interested in

inotifywait -m -e create "$directory" |
while read folder eventlist eventfile
do
    echo "the following events happened in folder $folder:"
    echo "$eventlist $eventfile"
done
```

Update:

If the problem goes complicated, for example you'll have to monitor recursive, dynamic directory structures, you should have a look at [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) It's a cron like daemon which executes scripts on certain events. But the events are file system events rather than timer events.

Comment: I tried your solution. I am getting "Setting up watches.  
Watches established. " in terminal and the program is not terminating . I am very new to inotify. so please clarify..

Comment: Make some changes in the folder an you'll see. :) The program will never terminate in it's current version. It will wait forever for changes. Note that I'll be AFK for a while. Will return back here later.

Comment: OK, where shall i find the results of inotify , is it inside "directory="/tmp" (i changed tmp according to my need) ?? but i am not getting anything inside that folder !!!

Comment: `inotifywait` produces no output. Refer to the man page that I've linked. You may also google this. I just wanted to point you in the right direction

Comment: thanks "hek2mgl". your solution works, but it does not work for directories inside the mentioned directory, can you please suggest the solution for the same too, voted for your comment :)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. And it will need some effort to craft a recursive shell script which also respects when new directories will be created or deleted. I've currently done this with PHP. :) You should have a look at [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) This might be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for incron suggestion, but I am not getting more details about incron, i would like to request you  to provide the solution in inotify if its possible for you, voted for your answer :)

Comment: as I said, will be AFK for a while. need to hurry now. Will return later here

Comment: Use the `-r` flag with `inotifywait` to watch all subdirectories. Please, read the man page for `inotifywait`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for `-r`. I wasn't knowing that. What if a subdirectory will be created in such a folder? will it automatically being watched? (I know I could test this, but have not much time at the moment)

Comment: Yeah I see!!! :) just had a look there! many thanks! sometimes I don't read the man page because I think I'm already knowing this, but that was wrong in this case :)

Comment: @chepner Can I ask you what do you think about `incron` ? have you experience with it? I've only heard about sometimes

Comment: Never heard of it, but sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option to 'inotifywait':

-d --daemon
    Same as --monitor, except run in the background logging events to a  file
    that must be specified by --outfile. Implies --syslog.

For completeness:

-m --monitor
    Instead  of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely.
    The default behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.

Within the do-done block of your 'while' statement, you might parse each event report for interesting details then use 'case-esac' to take action based on each event that you care about.

For something that you plan to rely on for your operations, you might also consider replacing the hard-coded '$directory' with some sort of configuration file. Such a file might include the path and filename, the interesting events for that path and file, and a script to run when those events happened.
The script might take the list of events as parameters and then 'case-esac' again.

Just one man's ramblins,
~~~ 8d;-Dan