# How to run inotifywait continuously and run it as a cron or deamon?

Tags: linux, shell, init, inotify

I've built a `shell` script that uses `inotifywait` to automatically detect file changes on a specific directory. When a new PDF file is dropped in the directory this script should go off and it should then trigger `ocropus-parser` to execute some commands on it. The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
inotifywait -m ~/Desktop/PdfFolder -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
    #echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
    # Check if the file is a PDF or another file type.
    if [ $(head -c 4 "$file") = "%PDF" ]; then
        echo "PDF found - filename: " + $file
        python ocropus-parser.py $file
    else
        echo "NOT A PDF!"
fi
done
```

This works pretty well when I run this script through the terminal with `./filenotifier.sh` but when I reboot my `Linux` (Ubuntu 14.04) my shell will no longer run and it will not restart after a reboot.
I've decided to create an init script that starts at boot time (I think). I did this by copying the file `filenotifier.sh` to `init.d`:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/PdfFolder/filenotifier.sh /etc/init.d/
```

I've then gave the file the correct rights:

```
sudo chmod 775 /etc/init.d/filenotifier.sh
```

and finally I've added the file to `update-rc.d`:

```
sudo update-rc.d filenotifier.sh defaults
```

However when I reboot and drop a PDF in the folder `~/Desktop/PdfFolder` nothing will happen and it seems that the script does not go off.
I'm really not experienced with `init.d`, `update-rc.d` and `deamon` so I'm not sure what is wrong and if this is even a good approach or not.

Thanks,
Yenthe

Comment: did you mean "cron" or "crohn"? I can't find anything about "crohn" except for the disease.

Comment: `cron` can be a disease too, depending on the way it's configured.

Comment: @ErikAllik thanks for the heads up, I've corrected myself! And Frédéric, this already makes me think I made a bad choice using cron?

Comment: @Yenthe, well, `cron` is not really the right tool for scheduling a script to run on boot. Modifying `rc.local` (or your distribution's equivalent) seems like a better idea.

Comment: Show us your crontab and your init.d script, then we can tell you what's wrong and what can be improved. Also, tell us what init system you are using: you know, many distributions switched to systemd, and if that is your case, someone may provide a systemd-specific solution

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini my init.d script is an exact copy of filenotifier.sh (as posted in my answer) as for the crontab: I didn't even think I needed one? Because my init.d goes of a bootup, no? I use Ubuntu 14.04 so I believe that is Upstart being used. Kernel version 3.13.0-36-generic

Comment: @Yenthe: you mention cron in your question. I understood that you have a cron job that is creating a file in `/etc/init.d`, am I wrong?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I have made an exact copy of filenotifier.sh (under /Desktop/PdfFolder) and placed that under /etc/init.d, I have the filenotifier.sh file (under /etc/init.d) permissions with 775 and then ran the update-rc.d command on it.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I got it: you're not using cron at all. You're using the term "cron" but you mean "init script". (The real cron is [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples).)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I think you might be right there, I'm afraid my knowledge of this part of Linux is very low. The filenotifier.sh script should just be started when a reboot is done so that it is running at all times and always detects new files dropped in a specific folder to execute some Python scripts.

Comment: Are you running your script as `root` or another user. If it is run by a non-root user then the `~/Desktop/PdfFolder` path will not point to the intended location (as init scripts are run by `root`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Being an init-script, you should add the [LSB header](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) to your script, like this:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
  # Provides:          filenotifier
  # Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
  # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
  # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
  # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
  # Short-Description: Something
  # Description:       Something else
  ### END INIT INFO

  inotifywait -m ...
  ```

  This way, you can ensure that your script runs when all mount points are available (thanks to `Required-Start: $remote_fs`). This is essential if your home directory is not on the root partition.
- Another problem is that in your init-script you're using `~`:

  ```
  inotifywait -m ~/Desktop/PdfFolder ...
  ```

  The `~` expands to the current user home directory. Init-scripts are run as root, so it'll expand to `/root/Desktop/PdfFolder`. Use `~<username>` instead:

  ```
  inotifywait -m ~yenthe/Desktop/PdfFolder ...
  ```

  (Assuming that your username is `yenthe`.)

  Or perhaps switch user before starting (using `sudo`).
- `$file` is the basename without the path to the directory. Use `"$path/$file"` in your commands:

  ```
  "$(head -c 4 "$path/$file")"
  python ocropus-parser.py "$path/$file"
  ```

  Maybe consider using `name` instead of `file`, to avoid confusion.
- If things are not working, or if in general you want to investigate something, remember to use `ps`, like this:

  ```
  ps -ef | grep inotifywait
  ```

  `ps` will tell you, for example, whether your script is running and if `inotifywait` was launched with the correct arguments.
- Last but not least: use `"$file"`, not `$file`; use `"$(head -c 4 "$file")"`, not `$(head -c 4 "$file")`; use `read -r`, not `read`. These tips can save you a lot of headaches in the future!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is a great one! I have on strange issue though. When I run the filenotifier.sh from Desktop/PdfFolder it will work fine and detect the file. When I run it from within /etc/init.d and when I drop a file in the folder I will get an error: `head: cannot open ‘test.pdf’ for reading: No such file or directory` why is this the case? It knows the file and the path since it can print the name.
The code for the head looks like this now: `if [ "$(head -c 4 "$file")" = "%PDF" ]; then`

Comment: @Yenthe: `$file` is the basename without the path. Use `"$path/$file"`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm wondering two more things: why should I use `"$file"` in place of `$file` and why should I use `read -r` in place of `read`? Thanks a lot for your time and detailed answer! One of the best answers I've seen around.

Comment: @Yenthe: if `$file` contains spaces, then it will be expanded to multiple arguments (try it). The situation is even worse if `$file` contains shell code: that code will be executed (don't try it)! The `-r` option tells `read` to ignore backslash escapes. Try creating a file named e.g. `\n`

Comment: I never knew this, thanks a lot. Accepted & upvote your answer by the way! Keep up the good work. :-)

Answer (score 5):

For that purpose the developers of `inotify` created [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). It is a cron like daemon which executes scripts based on changes in a watched file/directory rather than on time events.

Comment: Is there a big benefit to using incron in place of inotifywait? In essence it seems to do the same as me making update-rc.d and adding commands in it?

Comment: It's better to maintain. It has logging facilities, etc. As I said, the developers of inotify (including tools like inotifywait) created it.