# bash & inotify - monitoring and moving file

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, inotify

I'm not an advanced user of Linux, but I'm looking for some **simple script** in bash which will be working in cron or any other way and **in 5-10 minutes period time** will be **looking** for **new files**, after **new directory/files** are already uploaded to the directory **script will move** new directory with files **to other location**.

I found **inotify** which can be a great solution for this, but the issue is how to go with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062806/inotify-how-to-use-it-linux

Comment: But i think its not related answer for my question.
I`m looking for solution which will move "new" files to new place.

Comment: Use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). It's from the developers of inotify and made for that purpose. Anyway your question here is too broad.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using inotifywait to recognize that some filesystem change ocurred in certain path.

Take a look at:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

You can specify on what changes you are interested (delete, create, modify, etc.) and whether the script should output it or simply exit after change.

I've been using this tool in a way that my script was starting inotifywait and when it exists, do some action and restart inotifywait again.

Hope this helps.
Martin

Comment: I created something like this based on the many information in the internet but the pity is how to work with directory which contains some files.

`cd "$dir"`
 `inotifywait -m -r -q -e close_write --format %f . | while IFS= read -r      file;`do
  `mv -p "$file" "$target"`
      `echo "$file has been copied to the $target"`
   `done`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - "how to work with directory which contains some files"? What do you mean? What's the problem?

Comment: Ok again.  
I have some directory called for example "uploaded"  
I want to monitor this directory for some updates.  
  
From time to time this directory will contain files and directories and files in these directories.  
  
/uploaded/directory/file1.mpg  
/uploaded/directory/file2.txt  
/uploaded/directory2/file.avi  
/uploaded/directory3/file4.mpeg  
  
Then this files should be moved with his own structure to the new location after when all operation on file finished.  
  
/moved/directory/file1.mpg  
/moved/directory/file2.txt  
/moved/directory2/file.avi  
/moved/directory3/file4.mpeg

Comment: To maintain file structure, how about use rsync for it?

something like:

while [ true ]; do inotifywait -m -r -q (other options) && rsync -ar /uploaded/ /moved/ ; done

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync