# Inotify linux watching subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, inotify

is it possible to watch directories in this pattern /storage/data/usernames/Download/ -> /storage/data/*/Download/ I need to watch if changes are made in Download folder of each user. Maybe i need to create list of all paths, put it in array and with loop start inotify processes on each folder, but this may be to heavy for system.

Comment: You want `inotifywait` and you set it on the parent and it can watch for any of the changes you specify (e.g. create, modify, delete, etc..) recursively. It will output the name of the file changed in that directory structure. If you have two directories that are not part of a related hierarchy (e.g. parent/child) then set two watches.

Comment: the problem is that i need to skip all other folders except of Download dirs in each user homedir.

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive, you can just specify a bunch of different directories to watch. You can even list the files to watch in a file and initialize the watch with the `--fromfile <file>` option (one file/directory per line) So one watch can cover all the home directories. It will need to be run by a user with sufficient permissions to read (and execute if you want to descend within directories in home).

Comment: folders are created dynamically that's why i want to skip username part and watch all folders with name Download.

Comment: Thank you for hint about --fromfile option, i think i will run script to get all paths and save them in list file and use this option to monitor.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, it is easily possible.**

> folders are created dynamically that's why i want to skip username
>   part and watch all folders with name Download.

[fluffy](https://github.com/tinkershack/fluffy#dont-mind-getting-your-hands-dirty) is the right tool for it.

1. Open a terminal:1, run `fluffy`
2. In another terminal:2, `fluffyctl -W /storage/data/*/Download`
3. You must be able to see events on terminal:1 where `fluffy` was invoked.
4. When ever you add a new user but wish not to reexecute fluffy to update the path, run the same watch command again `fluffyctl -W /storage/data/*/Download` after you have added a new user; picks up the new user directory with the same settings/choices. If you have removed any user, don't have to bother, fluffy takes care of releasing the resources by itself.

**Commands for your use case:**

dir contents -

```
root@six-k:/opt# ls /opt/*/d1
/opt/d1/d1:
fd1

/opt/dd2/d1:
fd1

/opt/dd3/d1:
```

invoke `fluffy` -

```
root@six-k:/home/lab/fluffy# fluffy
```

control/manage fluffy -

```
root@six-k:/opt# fluffyctl -W /opt/*/d1
```

events -

```
root@six-k:/home/lab/fluffy# fluffy

event:  ACCESS, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/d1/d1

event:  CLOSE_NOWRITE, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/d1/d1

event:  ACCESS, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/dd2/d1

event:  CLOSE_NOWRITE, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/dd2/d1

event:  ACCESS, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/dd3/d1

event:  CLOSE_NOWRITE, ISDIR, 
path:   /opt/dd3/d1
```

Note:
`inotifywait` is not elegant, it is buggy and reports false event paths. I do not wish to review `inotifytools` here, but if you are curious to know what is wrong with it, watch a directory tree and perform renames/moves with in it. Later do an `ls` on that renamed directory, see what path it reports!

Comment: Are you the creator of `fluffy`? That should probably be noted in the answer.