# monitor local file excution/access history triggered by a remote server

Tags: ssh, centos7

My question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062806/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-inotify#_=_), but a little different from that:

I want to monitor the file execution/access history on a CentOS 7.2 machine. I know that a remote server is calling some files on my local machine through SSH in order to finish some tasks, so I want to find out what files on my local machine that the server is calling.
I tried to use the terminal command:

```
ls -lu
```

but it didn't show any invocation history that was triggered by the remote server through SSH. Later I learned about inotify. But I also heard that it's not available on Centos 7. Is it true? If not, how should I use it? I didn't find a dirty and quick inotify tutorial for centos. Is there any system logs that records this type of information? Any other ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: "a remote server is calling some files on my local machine..." How is this remote server accessing the local files? Through NFS? SSH? SFTP? Something else?

Comment: @Kenster Through SSH. Thanks I added that information to the questions

Comment: SSH isn't inherently a file-access protocol. What is this remote program invoking through ssh to access these files?

Comment: @Kenster Some scripts. Python or bash scripts or both.